# In Office JS Add-In for Outlook or Word, is there an api to replace or change text in certain character locations?

Tags: outlook, ms-word, office-js

For an Add-In for Outlook or Word, I saw the API function: `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", callback)` to get the content of the email, but I also need a function to replace/change the text at certain character locations, something like: replaceText(startChar, endChar, replacementText).

Is there such thing?

Comment: You can try using the API [`setSelectedDataAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=word-js-preview#setselecteddataasync-data--options--callback-).

Comment: This is only for a selection made by the user. What if I want to change the text in a place regardless the selection?

Comment: Word's JS API does not have a way to specify character position since this is simply unreliable due to the way Word manages its content. You could get the entire content in a string, manipulate that and write it back (replacing the existing content). There's also the `search` method if you have another way of identifying it. Or if you know the index of the *word* or *paragraph* (rather than a character).

Comment: @CindyMeister what is the API to (1) change the entire content (2) change a word or paragraph by their index?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible today. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins).

It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the existing [request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/39718654-outlook-replace-text-at-specific-location). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: That's a shame, since it's a very useful, basic and required functionality. Google Docs extensions have this functionality a long time ago...